# copy a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, osx-yosemite

The goal is simple. I would like to write a javascript script for Finder performing 'copy to' operation. I can't figure out how to work with ObjectSpecifiers.

An other question. Does anyone know a repository of simple javascript scripts (for automation) suitable for learning this technique/API? The library and documentation provided by Apple isn't much helpful.

Here is the code I tried.

```
finder = Application('Finder');
finder.includeStandardAdditions = true;
var selection = finder.selection();
var file = selection[0];
//var target = finder.startupDisk.folders.byName("Users").folders.byName("me");
var target = finder.home;
//file instanceof ObjectSpecifier;
//target instanceof ObjectSpecifier;
finder.move(selection,target);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm stuck with this same question myself! BTW, what error are you getting when you run the above?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your last line you meant to use 'file' and not 'selection', but if you replace your move call on the last line with this line below, I think this is what you want (I added the extra optional parameters too from the docs just so you get a feel for them if you wanted those specified too):

```
finder.duplicate(file, {to: target, replacing:true, exactCopy:true});
```